# loop incrementation within for loop python

Tags: iteration, extend

this list contains random numbers and the for loop iterates through it up to around 1/3 of its length
and prints out all the odd numbers up to that range.
I am trying to extend the range every time the counter increases but it looks like that my code
ignores this direction and keeps considering only the first established range parameter.
Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?
N.B the ultimate goal is to be able to increase the loop range while iterating, nothing else.

```
 import math

list_1=[1,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,17,19,20,1,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,17,19,20,1,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,17,19,20]
r_length= math.ceil(len(list_1)/3)
print(r_length,len(list_1))

rlist=[]
loop_range=1
odd_nrs=[]
for i in range( r_length*loop_range):
    if list_1[i]%2==0:
        loop_range+=1
        continue
    rlist.append((loop_range))
    print(list_1[i])
    odd_nrs.append(list_1[i])

print(rlist[-1],'rlist')
print(len(odd_nrs),'odd nrs length')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the error is that you can't change the number of iterations mid-loop.
So I have tried this, and it worked fine in python 3.8:

```py
import random

list = random.sample(range(200), 50) # List
third_of_list_length = len(list) // 3 # The // operator only gives out the int part. Add 1 for the ceiling.
    
print(third_of_list_length, len(list))
    
start_index = 0
odd_nums = []
odd_nums_collected = 0
    
while True: # Each iteration, scan more of the list if there are new odd numbers.
    for i in range(start_index, third_of_list_length + start_index):
        if (list[i] % 2) and (list[i] not in odd_nums):
            odd_nums.append(list[i])
            odd_nums_collected +=  1

    if odd_nums_collected > 0:
        start_index += 1
        odd_nums_collected = 0
        continue
    else:
        break

print("Odd numbers: ", odd_nums)
```

By the way, are you trying to save performance with this?

Comment: I know there is  a easier way to filter odd numbers but like I specified above, that is not the point. The goal is to increment the range every time the counter increases. I came up with the odd numbers task just to have something to experiment my code with.

Comment: @d8a988 But do you mean, like, only scan the first part of the list and then if an odd number is found, extend the number of items scanned by 1? I don't really understand what you want to do...

Comment: you said it, scan until the condition is met, and then keep scanning but increase the iteration by one everytime the condition is met.